# C# High speed MD5/SHA hash over network

Tags: c#, performance, networking, md5, sha

In a C# project that I am currently working on, we're attempting to calculate the MD5 of a large quantity of files over a network (current pot is 2.7 million, client pot may be in excess of 10 million).  With the number of files that we are processing, speed is of the issue.

The reason we do this is to verify the file was copied to a different location without modification.

We currently use the following code to calculate the MD5 of a file

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

byte[] hashMD5 = null;

try
{
   // Open stream to file to get MD5 hash for, create hash
   using (FileStream fsMD5 = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
      hashMD5 = md5.ComputeHash(fsMD5);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   clsLogging.logError(clsLogging.ErrorLevel.ERROR, ex);
}

string md5sum = "";
if (hashMD5 != null)
{
   // Change hash into readable text
   foreach (byte hex in hashMD5)
      sb.Append(hex.ToString("x2"));
    md5sum = sb.ToString();
}
```

However, the speed of this isn't what my manager has been hoping for.  We've gone through a number of changes to the way and number of files that we calculate the MD5 for (i.e. we don't do it for files that we don't copy... until today when my manager changed his mind so **ALL** files must have a MD5 calculated for them, in case at some future time a client wishes to bugger with our program so all files are copied i guess)

I realize that the speed of the network is probably a major contributing factor (100Mbit/s).   Is there an efficient way to calculate the MD5 of the contents of a file over a network?

Thanks in advance.
Trevor Watson

Edit: put all code in block instead of just a part of it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't verify the hashes locally on the machine to which the files were copied?

Comment: First point of business is to figure out the bottleneck. Have you ran any benchmarks to see how fast the process takes just reading the file and iterating as you are without computing the hash? Then with the hash; how much overhead is the computation taking? Have you performed the same task locally?

Comment: I agree with Aaron: The time needed to calculate the hash is the sum of: opening the remote file over network, seeking to the beginning on the drive, reading from drive, streaming contents over network, calculating the hash. Any of it can cause a bottleneck. Some of these can be done in parallel for different files as Andrew Cooper suggested.

Comment: Tell your manager that he needs to buy a faster disk.  This code is purely disk I/O bound, not CPU bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck is that the whole file must be streamed/copied over the network, and your seems to look good...
the different hash functions (md5/sha256/sha512) have almost the same computation time

Two possible solutions for this problem:

1) run a hasher on the remote system and store the hashes in to separate files - if that is possible in your environment.

2) Create a part-wise hash of the file, so that you only copy a part of the file.
I mean something like that:

```
part1Hash = md5(file.getXXXBytesFromFileAtPosition1)
part2Hash = md5(file.getXXXBytesFromFileAtPosition2)
part3Hash = md5(file.getXXXBytesFromFileAtPosition3)
finalHash = part1Hash ^ part2Hash ^ part3Hash;
```

you have to test which part of the file are optimal to read, so the hashes stay unique.

hope that helps...

edit: changed to bitwise xor

Comment: When combining the hashes you'd be much better off using bit-wise XOR.  Using OR will result in a hash with many more 1's than 0's and a much greater chance of hash collisions.

Comment: If you can't install something on the client side then go with #2 here. Bandwidth is your enemy here, especially since 100MBit/s is only theoretical and doesn't account for other people on the network. It is theoretically possible for someone to break this type of algorithm but if they do you can report them to the NSA and they'll be taken away. Read a couple of blocks of bytes and hash them. The more bytes the better but you'll need to tweak based on performance.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice.  We're trying to look at creating a program to calculate the hash values on client machines.  Hopefully, that will give us a way of doing it.  And we could possibly use those machine's processing power for files on a UNC path as well.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach would be to make use of the parallel task library in .Net 4.0.  100Mbps will still be a bottleneck, but you should see a modest improvement.

I wrote a small application last year that walks the top levels of a folder tree checking folder and file security settings.  Running over a 10Mbps WAN it took about 7 minutes to complete one of our large file shares.  When I parallelised the operation the execution time came down to a bit over 1 minute.

Comment: We unfortunately don't have access to the .NET 4.0 library.  I might try to see if creating multiple threads for calculating the hash value of the file in chunks.  I saw a post on here somewhere about hashing parts of a file to get a MD5 of the overall file.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try installing a 'client' on each one which listens on a port and when signaled, will calculate the MD5 hash for the files requested.

The main server will then only need to ask each client to calculate the MD5. Using this distributed approach you will gain the combined speed of all the clients and reduce network congestion.

Comment: This won't work if the file server is a NAS device with a proprietary OS.

Comment: For every device on the network, keep a flag to check if it has a client. If it does, use that, else use the current approach ... I know this is getting complex and has its own issues but it will help both speed and network.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. We're trying to look at creating a program to calculate the hash values on client machines. Hopefully, that will give us a way of doing it. And we could possibly use those machine's processing power for files on a UNC path as well